# C# program to check if file exists /time out and run

Tags: c#, timer, iterator

I need to create a C# program which will check if input.txt exists (within a time-out of 5 mins), if within 5 mins the input.txt is created it will copy contents to output.txt. Then it has to delete the input.txt (and keep iterating for 10000 runs).

I am doing this to avoid a license re-launch within the program which takes quite sometime compared to program execution.

I tried with timers, Filewatcher but got totally lost.

Can someone help?

[image: Flow chart]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? Please remember that SO is not a free coding service, but here to help you with _specific_ programming problems.

Comment: going to need to see your code

Comment: just pointing out here if we take the 5 minute interval and 10000 iterations we come up with approximately 34 days that this will be running........anyways.  Look at threading and System.IO.File.Exists, System.IO.File.Delete, System.IO.File.AppendText.  Should be pretty trivial to implement.

Comment: Use a [Stopwatch class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) and check the ElapsedMilliseconds property when file does not exist to determine whether you have exceeded your 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your flow chart for reference and it alone I managed to come up with this piece of code:

```
string inputPath = "<input.txt file path>";
string outputPath = "<output.txt file path>";

for (int iterator = 0; iterator < 10000; iterator++)
{
    bool exists = false;
    long startTimeMillis = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

    while (!exists)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond - startTimeMillis >= 5 * 60 * 1000) Environment.Exit(0);

        if (File.Exists(inputPath))
        {
            exists = true;

            FileStream f = File.Open(inputPath, FileMode.Open);
            String output = String.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
            {
                output += (char)f.ReadByte();
            }
            f.Dispose();

            File.WriteAllText(outputPath, output);
            File.Delete(inputPath);
        }
    }
}

Environment.Exit(0);
```

I can't guarantee that my code is *100%* applicable for your purposes but it shouldn't be too hard to implement. If need be you can run this code from within a Thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Keve1227